# strange syntax error in python, version 2.6 and 3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

this may not be an earth-shattering deficiency of python, but i still
wonder about the rationale behind the following behavior: when i
run

```
source = """
print( 'helo' )
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print( 'yeah!' )

#"""

print( compile( source, '<whatever>', 'exec' ) )
```

i get ::

```
  File "<whatever>", line 6
    #
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i can avoid this exception by (1) deleting the trailing `#`; (2)
deleting or outcommenting the `if __name__ == '__main__':\n
print( 'yeah!' )` lines; (3) add a newline to very end of the
source.

moreover, if i have the source end without a trailing newline right
behind the `print( 'yeah!' )`, the source will also compile without
error.

i could also reproduce this behavior with python 2.6, so it’s not new
to the 3k series.

i find this error to be highly irritating, all the more since when i
put above source inside a file and execute it directly or have it
imported, no error will occur—which is the expected behavior.

a `#` (hash) outside a string literal should always represent the
start of a (possibly empty) comment in a python source; moreover, the
presence or absence of a  `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause should
not change the interpretation of a soure on a syntactical level.

can anyone reproduce the above problem, and/or comment on the
phenomenon?

cheers

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. Bizarre - I'm interested in the answer too.

Comment: Reproduced in 2.6.1. It does seem to be a bug to me too, but it's a pretty extreme edge case.

Comment: You could put your "update" as the answer and accept that.

Comment: you may call it an edge-case but it does have the power to become a show-stopper until intense head-scratching and fumbling-araound lets you go on with your daily work; insofar fixing it is worth-while. the problem here is that it is so obscure and hard to google.

Comment: You found the solution! Good for you, but the question is 'stuck' as unanswered. Perhaps you could post the solution as an answer to your own question, and accept it later on? :)

Comment: thanks for pointing out to close the question, i overlooked that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## update

turns out this is indeed a bug as pointed out by http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/b4842cc7abd75fe9; the bug report is at http://bugs.python.org/issue1184112; it appears to be fixed in 2.7 and 3.2.

## solution

once recognized, this bug is extremely simple to fix: since a valid python source should stay both syntactically valid and semantically unchanged when a newline is added to the source text, just mechanically do just that to any source text. this reminds me of the `;` semicolon you mechanically put in between source texts when assembling a multi-file javascript source for efficient gzipped delivery to the remote client.